# Ipad 10.2" for a PhD: 32 or 128 GB?

Tags: ipad, memory, pdf, hardware-recommendation

I hope this is the right community:

I'm a first year PhD student in Mathematics, and I plan to buy an Ipad 10.2" with the Apple Pencil as I have seen that it can be quite useful to take notes when I'm at the campus, and it's easily portable.

**My main concern is about memory**: *I really don't know if I should take the 32GB or the 128GB*.

In order to provide additional information: as a Mathematics student, I'm sure I will use intensively **Notability** or similar apps, and I think I will need to download PDFs with papers and stuff like that. For instance, if I plan to take notes using the Ipad, will I run out of memory with 32GB?

Comment: The rule for configuring any computing device, get as much storage and RAM as you possibly can. In this case you can't configure RAM. This is **really** just a question of budget: if you can afford more get it. I've never met anyone who has regretted getting more RAM (or a bigger HD/SSD)

Comment: The memory here is not RAM but storage space

Answer (score 2):

As @benwiggy pointed out correctly, storage always tends to run short.

Of course, such a topic is a matter of personal opinion. Trying to keep objective, please consider the following:

- The 32 GB option is the "entry-level" option—in fact, no other iPad even offers such a low option anymore! (iPad Air and iPad mini start at 64 GB; iPad Pro at 128 GB.) It is safe to assume that it's on the market solely as a cheap entry model to the Apple universe.
- Getting the model with more storage will, even if you have no use for it now, increase the device's value down the line. I, for one, tend to sell my old Apple devices (usually after upgrading to a newer model): the resale value of a 32 GB devices will be considerably less than the same device with 128 GB.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question "do I need more storage" is always 'yes'. [Parkinson's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law) dictates that data expands to fill the space available.

However, my "PhD" folder on my Mac is 1GB. This contains my thesis documents, with 230 vector illustrations; research notes; over 100 downloaded JSTOR papers and PDFs of other theses.

I could add to that 12 GB of reference material as scanned images.

But of course, you'll need to factor in what form your data will be in, and all the apps you plan to add, and any other data that you might want to hold, such as the new pop music that the students like.

Comment: Honestly, I don't plan to add apps that are not used for the PhD, i.e. spotify or similar, as I have them  already on my phone. What I will do, essentially, is: taking notes, download PDFs like you did and not much more. I'm worried that taking notes will use lots of memory. Does it happen in your experience?

Comment: @Vefhug Your needs may change over time, iOS and Apps will get bigger as well, you may want to load more books related to your research etc. So unless your main constraint is available cash, go with the 128 model :-)

Comment: @Vefhug My notes were pure text. (The entire Bible as text is only 5 MB.) If your notes are going to include non-text data that takes more space, or you're using a Note-taking app that has its own data format, then you may need more space.

Comment: @benwiggy Side question: if I have a MacBook Pro, can I use iCloud to have more memory on my iPad?

Comment: You can have a bigger iCloud storage than your laptop holds, yes. So all your files are 'in iCloud', and you download some as required. Though I'd certainly want to make local backups to prepare for problems.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this all depends on your use and needs. But to put this into perspective, this is a selection of my older iPad pro (I have used 103GB of 256GB):

- The operating system, iPadOS, will use about 10GB of storage.
- A downloaded movie will use as much as 5GB
- 2500 notes in Evernote takes up 250MB (I suspect it's not storing
  them all on iPad)
- 6 Books in Audible need 1GB
- Spotify, with downloads, is 1GB
- 254 PDF and ePUB books uses 2.8GB
- My music library is 14GB

So that's 12GB remaining if you don't have a music library, and if you do, then you can not store it on the iPad as you are out of space. Forget downloading a season of a Netflix show for the lonely hotel room.

So, even light use will consume 50% of your storage quickly. The nice thing about an iPad is how useful it is for watching movies, youtube/lectures and the like, especially when traveling.

The biggest challenge with 32GB is that it limits your use of the device, and the longevity of the device, should you wish to repurpose it, or if you find an app that will greatly aid in your research. As you can see, if you use the iPad exclusively for note and pdf/books, perhaps 32GB will suffice. But I would never recommend it.

In fact, if your intended use is note taking and books only, AND the difference in price is a **burden**, I would even recommend you consider a refurbished older model from the Apple Store with 128GB or higher, rather than a new one with 32GB.

Good luck with your studies!

Comment: Thanks ! Your last paragraph makes the point, I think. The closest older model which would be?

Comment: For instance, the iPad 9.7 ?

Comment: Personally, I would recommend going no lower than an iPad that includes an A10 chip.  This is for performance and longevity reasons(iPadOS upgrade support). Last year models were A10 - A12. So this would include the iPad 6th generation(9.7), 7th gen (10.2), iPad Air 3rd gen (10.5), and iPad Pro 10.5.  Of course, any of the new iPad 8th gen or iPad Air 4th gen are fantastic, but full priced.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, really precious. If I already have a Macbook, I can take the 32GB because the memory is "shared" somehow, right? @cmason

Comment: No, there is no shared storage

Comment: really? It seemed to me that with iCloud I would have much more space

Comment: @Vefhug iCloud does allow you to store documents via Files, but apps need to be on the iPad storage. you can stream music or videos if you have wifi or carrier access, but my experience is that streaming movies is not reliable when traveling in hotels and airplanes